# Postmate : schedule a create delivery

Tags: postmates

I want to schedule a delivery rather than the ETA time provided by the POSTMATE api in response.
Because the customer wants a delivery at some specific time. 
How to schedule a ETA?

I didn't found a documentation for it in postmate api documentation.
I am using a CREATE DELIVERY api endpoint to generate the order delivery.

Comment: You may have to resort to a cronjob for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

**You can pass param like**

Pickup and dropoff windows are specified using pickup_ready_dt, pickup_deadline_dt, dropoff_ready_dt, and dropoff_deadline_dt.

pickup_ready_dt must be less than 30 days in the future.

pickup_deadline_dt must be at least 10 mins later than pickup_ready_dt and at least 20 minutes in the future, thus providing a realistic pickup window.

dropoff_ready_dt must be less than or equal to pickup_deadline_dt. This is to prevent a scenario where a courier has to hold onto an order between the pickup and dropoff windows.

dropoff_deadline_dt must be at least 20 mins later than dropoff_ready_dt, thus providing a realistic dropoff window.

dropoff_deadline_dt must be greater than or equal to pickup_deadline_dt.